# Magento Module Development

Tags: magento

I need to modify *Menu.php* located at *app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Menu.php*. My question is can I change the directory path to *local* (*app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Menu.php*) without having any issues in the future?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for overriding a Magento core class is explained in the [following article](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/)

You need to create your own basic module, and rewrite the core class to point to your module's class. That class may then extend the existing Magento core class, overriding or extending any methods.

*However*, you could simply copy the file and its path to the local directory, since Magento's autoloader defaults there first when looking for classes. The problem with this is that, when you decide to upgrade Magento, you must fully copy the new file to your path (if it were modified by the upgrade) and reapply your modifications.

The rewrite/extend is a much more maintainable solution, but the latter is quick and easy. The choice is yours!

Comment: I see, I just need to add some classes to implement Boostrap. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure thing! If my answer helped please mark as correct and/or upvote!